# Jquery DataTable TableTool not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: c#, flash, firefox, datatables, tabletools

I am using Jquery DataTable TableTool in my MVC4 ASP.NET web application. Export to Excel and PDF working well with Chrome. But not working in IE and FireFox.
My code is given below

```
 dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": "../media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [ 
                           {
                               "sExtends": "xls",
                               "sFileName": "Orders.csv",
                               "bFooter": false,
                               "mColumns": "visible",
                               "bHeader":false
                           }

                           ]
            },
```

Any one please help me

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Please show your html markup for the table you are targeting.  Note that it will only work on tables with well-formed html.

Comment: see this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/28694547/1407478

Comment: tablestools has a dependency on browser flash support. make sure you have installed this. In chrome its working means, you have set swf path right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oTable1 = $('#Ccctbl').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sDom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            "sAjaxSource": "/Setup/LoadCostCenterCategory/",
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "fnPreDrawCallback": function (oSettings, json) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $("#ToolTables_" + id + "_0").html("<i  class='icon-copy bigger-120 blue'></i>")
                $("#ToolTables_" + id + "_1").html("<i class='icon-file-text green bigger-120'></i>")
                $("#ToolTables_" + id + "_0").attr("title", "Copy");
                $("#ToolTables_" + id + "_1").attr("title", "Export To Excel");

            },
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                  {
                      'sExtends': 'copy',
                      "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                  },
                  {
                      'sExtends': 'xls',
                      "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                  }

                ]
            },
            "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "CODE", "sTitle": "Cost Center Category Code", "sWidth": "25%", "bSortable": false },
            { "mData": "DESCRIPTION", "sTitle": "Description", "sWidth": "25%", "bSortable": false },
            { "mData": "strsegcattype", "sTitle": "Segment", "sWidth": "25%", "bSortable": false },
            { "mData": "strIsActive", "sTitle": "Active", "sWidth": "25%", "bSortable": false },
            ]
        });
```

Comment: This code Working fine in all browser.
 You need to use following jquery,

 jquery.dataTables.min.js,
 jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js,
 TableTools.min.js,
 dataTables.tableTools.min.js